# how do i install opencart for my virtual server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, opencart2.3

I installed ubuntu 14 on my machine.I created multiple website using a single host.I installed opencart. Opencart works on the default website account but not on other website installed on the server.I copied the opencart files ( sudo cp /var/www/myweb/opencart to another website but it refused to copy.how do i install opencart on all website running on the machine

Comment: Please provide more details...

Comment: installed ubuntu on a machine then i went through the below steps to install multiple website

Comment: installed ubuntu on a machine then i went through the below steps to install multiple website 1)made a directory /var/www/mywebsite/public_html 2)ran the chown then chmod -R755 ,open the website sudo nano /var/www/mywebsite/public_html/index.html ,created my web page.ran sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.conf.changed added the server name  and server alais,enable the website and also restarted apache. installed opecart.and it installed in the path /var/www/html/opencart which is the default path of my server and not the virtual path

Comment: the path for my website is /var/www/mywebsite/public_html. opencart works for the default server but not for the other virtual websites.